# how to split one array in to multiple arrays based on clientID in php

Tags: php

I am trying to split the array and create for each clienID one new array. I have not yet manage how to split the array to two new arrays (example has two clientIDs). All rows with the same clientID should be in one array:

We can see that I have two clientIDs `'51df'` and `'51ff'`

File with raw data:

```
    clientID,Timestamp, Room temp., Pressure, Humidity, PM1.0, PM2.5
    51df,05/04/2021 11:20:42,22.28,988.61,37.97,0,0
    51ff,05/04/2021 11:20:53,22.29,988.57,37.95,0,0
    51df,05/04/2021 11:21:05,22.29,988.55,37.94,0,0
    51ff,05/04/2021 11:21:16,22.29,988.63,37.95,0,0
    51df,05/04/2021 11:21:27,22.28,988.57,37.97,1,1
    51ff,05/04/2021 11:21:38,22.30,988.61,37.95,1,1
    51df,05/04/2021 11:21:50,22.30,988.74,37.94,0,0
...

    array(24) { [0]=> array(7) 
{ [0]=> string(2) "ID" [1]=> string(9) "Timestamp" [2]=> string(16) "Room temperature" [3]=> string(8) "Pressure" [4]=> string(8) "Humidity" [5]=> string(5) "PM2.5" [6]=> string(5) "PM1.0" } [1]=> array(7) 
{ [0]=> string(22) "51df" [1]=> string(19) "05/04/2021 11:20:42" [2]=> string(5) "22.28" [3]=> string(6) "988.61" [4]=> string(5) "37.97" [5]=> string(1) "0" [6]=> string(1) "0" } [2]=> array(7) 
{ [0]=> string(22) "51ff" [1]=> string(19) "05/04/2021 11:20:53" [2]=> string(5) "22.29" [3]=> string(6) "988.57" [4]=> string(5) "37.95" [5]=> string(1) "0" [6]=> string(1) "0" } [3]=> array(7) 
{ [0]=> string(22) "51df" [1]=> string(19) "05/04/2021 11:21:05" [2]=> string(5) "22.29" [3]=> string(6) "988.55" [4]=> string(5) "37.94" [5]=> string(1) "0" [6]=> string(1) "0" } [4]=> array(7) 
{ [0]=> string(22) "51ff" [1]=> string(19) "05/04/2021 11:21:16" [2]=> string(5) "22.29" [3]=> string(6) "988.63" [4]=> string(5) "37.95" [5]=> string(1) "0" [6]=> string(1) "0" } [5]=>
...
```

What I have until now. I am reading all the file into an array and do the transition to split each row at ',', which gives me the above printout:

```
<?php
$latestFile = '/client/logs/logging_multipleClients.out';

$tmp = tail($latestFile, $lines = 400, $buffer = 4096);
$tmp1 = preg_split( "/\n/", $tmp );
$data = array();
$table = 'ID,Timestamp,Room temperature,Pressure,Humidity,PM2.5,PM1.0';
$tmp2 = preg_split( "/\,/", $table );
array_push($data, $tmp2);
for ($j=1; $j < count($tmp1); $j++) {
    $tmp2 = preg_split( "/\,/", $tmp1[$j] );
    array_push($data, $tmp2);
}

var_dump($data);
?>
```

How do I now split this `$data` array into two arrays according to the clientIDs?
So, at the end I would like to have:

```
client['0'] with all the row with clientIDs '51df'
client['1'] with all the row with clientIDs '51ff'
```

After I manage that it should be rather easy to split the `$data` array into as many clientIDs the file could have.

Would it be easier if I would read the file line by line, something like this:

```
    if (($handle = fopen($latestFile, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        $data = array();
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            // do something here to push each line to the correspondent client array according to the clientID.
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: _"Would it be easier if I would read the file line by line, something like this:"_ That's how I would do it.

Comment: I do agree, but I still get stuck on how to create a array and add the corresponding rows to the specific array!? I guess it is my lack of php knowledge.

Comment: Outside the loop, initialize the array with two empty sub-arrays. Inside the loop, if the id is `51df` then append the row to the first sub-array. If the id is `51ff` then append the row to the second sub-array.